# How do you set the background color for a variable height page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a web page that is minimum-height of 700px, but could be more. How do I use CSS to make sure that the body always has a background-color?

```
body {
  min-height: 700px;
  background: red;
}
```

will not work since the body height will only fill in up to 700px, and doesn't 'know' when the browser window is bigger.

Comment: Why would you want your `body` to have a min-height?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `height:auto`

```
body {
  height:auto;
  min-height: 700px;
  background: red;
}
```

But better use this setting to your wrapper div instead of body

Answer (score 1):

set the height and width of your body to 100%. then use divs (or, if html5, headers, sections, footers etc) to build your page structure. here's a basic example http://jsfiddle.net/AaDg5/

Comment: Sowmya's answer is only 1 line of code, but this will work as well. Thanks!